# One program about Remove Element is accepted but the other is not

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

What's the difference among the following two answers to [leetcode 27. Remove Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/)?
Both of them two returns the same output, but only no.1 was accepted. I have no idea why no.2 is not acceptable.

**Output**

```
#Output
[2,2]
```

**Programs**

no.1

```py
class Solution(object):
    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type val: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        for x in nums[:]:
            if x == val:
                nums.remove(x)

        return nums
```

no.2

```py
class Solution(object):
    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type val: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        result = [s for s in nums if s != val]
        result = str(result).replace(' ', '')
        return result
```

Comment: They dont return the same thing, the second one returns a string and it doesn't mutate the list

Comment: I fixed but still it doesn't work on leetcode platform.

Comment: again, **it doesn't mutate the list**

Comment: I've got rid of `len()`.

Comment: Do you understand what I'm saying? That isn't the *only* issue. Again, your second version *never mutates the original list as the problem specifies it should*.

Comment: Visible output `[2,2]` looks same on the two prgram, how can I distinguish *mutable list* or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your second function is returning the length of a string, and not the length of an actual list.

You can just print out your result variable, and you'll see that it includes characters like the opening & closing bracket, and the comma, which all add to the final length.